# capture subprocess output but print nothing to console?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run a curl command using subprocess. Works fine. I've got the output I need in a variable. The onlything I want is when the process runs, I don't want this printing in the console:

```
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
        100   255  100   153  100   102     56     37  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    56
```

Here's what that part of the script looks like:

```
        import subprocess

        def F_createSingleTable(table_name):
         un = "test"
         pw = "testpass"
         url = "https://blah.fake.url.com:7877/services/createstable"
         size = "10"
         size_til_archive = "30"
         retention = "5"
         curl_call =\
          [\
          'curl', \
          '-k', \
          '-u', \
          (un)+":"+(pw), \
          (url), \
          '-d', \
          'name='+(table_name), \
          '-d', \
          'size='+(size), \
          '-d', \
          'size_til_archive='+(size_til_archive), \
          '-d', \
          'retention='+(retention)\
          ]
         process = subprocess.run((curl_call), check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
         output = process.stdout
         if "already exists" in (output):
          print("table: "+(table_name)+" already exists")
```

if it matters the actual response I get which is stored in output is this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <response>
          <messages>
            <msg type="ERROR">table_name table already exists</msg>
          </messages>
        </response>
```

I don't need to save it, just check if 'alredy exists" is in it. Which I have and works.

Thanks

NOTE: I was originally wanting to use subprocess.call but I couldn't seem to capture the output to check if already exists was in the response

Comment: Tell curl to not report progress.

Comment: See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196549/hide-curl-output

Comment: Why are you using `curl` when Python has its own module for performing HTTP requests?

Comment: @Dan D. - dammit. what a "duh" response. Adding -s solved what I wanted. thanks

Comment: @Barmar I tried with requests originally. Wasnt sure how to build the call with it so i reverted to curl in the os

Comment: Post your attempt to use `requests` and someone will help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing on the console is on stderr, not stdout. In it's normal mode, curl prints the fetched content to stdout and the transfer stats to stderr. You can either suppress the statistics with the `-s`/`--silent` flag or discard stderr by passing `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` to your subprocess call.

If you care about the stderr output, you can also capture it separately by passing `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` or merge it into the stdout stream (obviously not recommended for the specific use case in the question) by passing `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

Comment: yeah.  -s to the original curl command solved it as per dan d's comment. i haven't slept... I shoulda thought of that. Though there are commands I run sometimes where the app isn't common and doesnt have a suppress built in, so it would be nice to do it at the subprocess level as well. 

I'll test this out too for my own knowledge growth.